# Can I use thinset instead of grout for mosaics?

Tags: material-selection

Do I have to use grout for my mosaics, or would filling in the gaps with thinset mortar (I am using thinset) be sufficient? What is the point of grouting if I can just use mortar to fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinset Mortar should be sufficient as a mortar [grout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grout) in your project.

> Thinset (also called thinset mortar, thinset cement, dryset mortar, or drybond mortar) is an adhesive mortar made of cement, fine sand and a water retaining agent such as an alkyl derivative of cellulose. [(1)](http://www.tiletools.com/mastic-vs-thinset-use/) It is usually used to attach tile or stone to surfaces such as cement or concrete. It is particularly **popular among mosaicists for outdoor applications** [(2)](https://mosaicartsupply.com/how-to-use-thinset/) - [Thinset (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinset)

Make sure you "use a wet toothbrush to scrub your grout joints clean as you are installing your floor ([Thinset Mortar Selection](http://www.floorstransformed.com/choosethinset.html)).

Comment: And don't try to wash thinset down the drain. It will clog your pipes.